# JavaScript button not running function or disappearing after clicked

Tags: javascript, css

EDIT: the issue was a typo, this should have been caught and is not a good question. Sorry about that

So I've been working on making one of my own projects in JS, and it involves lots of buttons. I have one button (The one with the ID of "firstbuildmulti1") which should run the function "build1multi1" But I don't think it is doing that. I've looked over it multiple times and I'm not sure why it won't work. Any help is appreciated! (Side note: the button only appears after you click the third building button, this is intentional). EDIT: I ran the code on here and it said:
{
  "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: b1m1cost is not defined",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 183,
  "colno": 17
}

My code is:

```js
  //declare variables for points, multiplier, buy upgrade, b1 2 and 3 cost and count, make point updater
var points = 9999;
var pointMulti = 1;
var buyupgrade = 0;
var b1cost = 200;
var b1count = 0;
var b2cost = 1000;
var b2count = 0;
var b3cost  = 2000;
var b3count = 0;
var b1m1cost = 1500;
var currentpoints = setInterval(pointupdate, 500);

//clicking on main button to add points
function addPoints() {
    points += pointMulti;
    var pointsArea = document.getElementById("pointdisplay");
    pointsArea.innerHTML = "You have " + Math.round(points) + " points!";
        if(points >= 100 && buyupgrade == 0) {
        var multiply_button = document.getElementById("btn_multiply");
        multiply_button.style.display = "inline";
        console.log();
    }
}

//make logic for doubling addpoints
function firstx2() {
  if (buyupgrade == 0) {
    pointMulti *= 2;
    buyupgrade++;
    points -= 100;
    var multiplierArea = document.getElementById("multidisplay");
    multiplierArea.innerHTML = "Your multiplier is: " + pointMulti;
    var multiply_button = document.getElementById("btn_multiply");
    multiply_button.style.display = "none";

  //logic for displaying first building upgrade
  if (buyupgrade == 1) {
    var firstbuild = document.getElementById("firstbuild");
    firstbuild.style.display = "inline";
    firstbuild.innerText = "Building 1. Cost " + b1cost;

    var show2ndx2 = document.getElementById("secondx2");
    multiply2.style.display = "inline";
  }

  }
}

//displays total points
function pointupdate() {
  document.getElementById("pointdisplay").innerHTML = "You have " + Math.round(points) + " points!";
}

//what happens when you click first building button
function build1() {
  if (points >= b1cost) {
    points -= b1cost;
    b1count++;
    b1cost *= 1.10;
    var b1multi = 1;
    var b1pps = b1count * b1multi;
    document.getElementById("b1").innerHTML = "You have " + b1count + " of building 1! Making " + b1pps + " points per second."
    firstbuild.innerText = "Building 1. Cost " + Math.round(b1cost);
    var build1add = setInterval(build1points, 1000);

    //display second building
    var secondbuild = document.getElementById("secondbuild");
    secondbuild.style.display = "inline";
    secondbuild.innerText = "Building 2. Cost " + b2cost;

  }
}

//what happens when you click second building button
function build2() {
  if (points >= b2cost) {
    points -= b2cost;
    b2count++;
    b2cost *= 1.10;
    var b2multi = 1;
    var b2pps = (b2count * 4) * b2multi;
    document.getElementById("b2").innerHTML = "You have " + b2count + " of building 2! Making " + b2pps + " points per second."
    secondbuild.innerText = "Building 2. Cost " + Math.round(b2cost);
    var build2add = setInterval(build2points, 1000);

    //display third building
    var thirdbuild = document.getElementById("thirdbuild");
    thirdbuild.style.display = "inline";
    thirdbuild.innerText = "Building 3. Cost " + b3cost;
  }
}

//what happens when you click third building button
function build3() {
  if (points >= b3cost) {
    points -= b3cost;
    b3count++;
    b3cost *= 1.10;
    var b3multi = 1;
    var b3pps = (b3count * 10) * b3multi;
    document.getElementById("b3").innerHTML = "You have " + b3count + " of building 3! Making " + b3pps + " points per second."
    thirdbuild.innerText = "Building 3. Cost " + Math.round(b3cost);
    var build3add = setInterval(build3points, 1000);

    //first building first multiplier
    var firstbuildmulti1 = document.getElementById("firstbuildmulti1");
    firstbuildmulti1.style.display = "inline";
    firstbuildmulti1.innerText = "Building 1 x2 multiplier. Cost: " + b1m1cost + "."
  }
}

//add points for build1
function build1points() {
  points += 1;
}

//add points for build2
function build2points() {
  points += 4;
}

//add points for build3
function build3points() {
  points += 10;
}

//second x2, display multiplier
function secondx2() {
  if (buyupgrade == 1 && points >= 1000) {
    pointMulti *= 2;
    points -= 1000;
    document.getElementById("multidisplay").innerHTML = "Your multiplier is: " + pointMulti;
    multiply2.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function build1multi1() {
  if (points >= b1m1cost) {
    points -= b1m1cost;
    b1multi *= 2;
    var build1multi1 = document.getElementById("build1multi1");
    build1multi1.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Click to get started!</p>

<!--Link to all CSS files -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="buttons.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="displayscores.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="layout.css">

<!-- make all buttons -->
<button id="addpoints" onclick="addPoints()" background-color:red>Add points</button>

<button id="firstbuild" onclick="build1()" style="display:none;">Building 1. Cost x</button>

<button id="secondbuild" onclick="build2()" style="display:none;">Building 2. Cost x</button>

<button id="thirdbuild" onclick="build3()" style="display:none;">Building 3. Cost x</button>

<br>
<p><b>Upgrades:</b></p>

<button id="btn_multiply" onclick="firstx2()" style="display:none;">x2 Multiplier. Cost: 100</button>

<button id="multiply2" onclick="secondx2()" style="display:none;">x2 Multiplier. Cost: 1000</button>

<button id="firstbuildmulti1" onclick="build1multi1()" style="display:none;">Building 1 x2 multiplier. Cost x</button>

<!-- make a div around all paragraphs displaying stats and display them -->
<div class="displayscores">
  <p id="pointdisplay"></p>
  <p id="multidisplay"></p>
  <p id="b1"></p>
  <p id="b2"></p>
  <p id="b3"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Missing parantheses `()` after `build1multi1` in the HTML. Should be `onclick="build1multi1()"`

Comment: @Vandesh I tried fixing that but it didn't change anything

Comment: Did you try a `console.log()` in the `build1multi1` function both, before and inside the condition? The condition `points>=b1m1cost` might be failing

Comment: @Vandesh How would I do that exactly? I'm still figuring this stuff out

Comment: Also, `b1m1cost` is only defined inside one of the functions and not globally, that might also be a probable cause.

Comment: This is your 6th question with this source code over the last 4 days... I would recommend you attempt something more simple and learn the basics of javascript because at this rate everyone who helps you of StackOverFlow are doing most of the work for you...

Comment: @Vandesh I tried that, it is now taking the points, but I don't believe it's doubling the multiplier or making the button disappear.

Comment: @NewToJS I know that I post here  lot, but I try to learn from what people tell me and only posts on here if I really try to fix it and can't find the issue. I've used what people say to learn how to implement it on my own and I believe it's helping me make lots of progress. I will try to post less on here today though.

Comment: Hard to go through the entire logic and work it out for you. But here's a general approach you should follow - 1. Check the console for errors, if any. 2. Put a `console.log()` at each conditional statement and check where the code is breaking.

Comment: It's good that you are learning from this and the point of this website is to post question. I'm just thinking you might find it easier to learn if you set your project to something a little less complicated and build your way up from there.

Comment: So, I changed your code to be a runnable snippet.  Run it, click your buttons, and note the error message that appears when clicking the button in question.

Comment: *Obi Wan Voice* "Joel... use the console..."  If you press F12 in your browser and click the Console tab, you will see error messages and console.log() statements from the page.  This is absolutely critical to debugging your code.

Comment: @Vandesh It says that it can't read property "style" of null, which is where I say to have it not be appeared. I'm not sure how to fix this because it doesn't say this for any of the other places I set it to none

Comment: @James Ok I tried that, it says {
  "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: b1m1cost is not defined",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 183,
  "colno": 17
} But I believe that is defined.

Comment: Let me just write it out in an answer for you

Comment: It's only defined using var within a different function, which means it's a local variable to that function, and not available to other functions.  You define globals at the top of your script but not for b1m1cost.

Comment: @James My bad, I had it that way on my text editor, Ill update it in the code. Still doesn't update the multiplier though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first, as discussed in the comments, anytime you're stuck with the code, you can try using `console.log()` (If you're new to it, research a bit on using the Console for debugging)

```
function build1multi1() {
  console.log("Entered function"); //If this is printed in console, that means the function is called
  if (points >= b1m1cost) {
    console.log("Entered condition"); //If this is not printed in console, it means condition points >= b1m1cost fails.
    // console.log(b1m1cost); // You can check b1m1cost value in the console
    // console.log(points); // You can check points value in the console
    points -= b1m1cost;
    b1multi *= 2;
    var build1multi1 = document.getElementById("build1multi1");
    build1multi1.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

**Problem 1 :** `b1m1cost` is not defined

`b1m1cost` is not defined in the global scope. It is only declared in one of the functions. Hence, the condition inside `build1multi1()` must be failing.

**Problem 2 :** Can't read property `style` of null (Doesn't hide the button)

This is happening inside the `build1multi1()` function.
 Which means `var build1multi1` inside that function is `null`.
 Which means `document.getElementById("build1multi1");` is unable to find any element with id `build1multi1`.
If you want to hide the button then the id should be `firstbuildmulti1` which is the id for the button. So, change it to `document.getElementById("firstbuildmulti1");`

Comment: Ok, I got it fixed so it does all the logic right, but it doesn't change the part where it displays the points per second, even though it should.

Comment: That is **your** logic. You should try and figure out using the `console.log()`s for different values as suggested. Good luck.

Comment: Actually, I got it to work now, I made more variables be global. Now it just isn't displaying the points per second correctly, but I think I can fix that.